# How to modify a Numpy array with conditional and function

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have a 3d with about 8e6 elements, and i need to change all of the elements.  I want to do something like this

```
def func(x, index):
....


flat = array.reshape(-1)
flat[flat == 9999] = 0
flat[flat >= 0.2 and flat < 0.7] = func(flat, 0)
flat[flat >= 0.7 and flat < 1.5] = func(flat, 1)
flat[flat >= 0.7 and flat < 1.5] = func(flat, 2)
....
...
```

This code doesnt work. I've tried np.nditer but it wouldnt let me retrieve the value per index, it seems to be retrieving the whole array.  in short of looping w/ a for loop per dimension and read and write each value, is there another way i can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using multiple conditionals for masking, you need to use bitwise operator `&`:

```
flat[(flat >= 0.2) & (flat < 0.7)] = ...
```

Additionally, as your mask dimensions and the result of the func might not be the same (looks to me that `func` does apply something to the whole array), you should do something like:

```
mask = (flat >= 0.2) & (flat < 0.7)
flat[mask] = func(flat, 0)[mask]
```

Or like this if your `func` is elementwise:

```
mask = (flat >= 0.2) & (flat < 0.7)
flat[mask] = func(flat[mask], 0)
```

Then repeat the same process for the other 2 conditions.

---

As a bonus, you can iterate over all your lower bounds ranges and do like this:

```
lower_bound = [0.2, 0.7, 1.5]
upper_bound = lower_bound[1:] + [np.inf]

for i in range(len(lower_bound)):
    mask = (flat >= lower_bound[i]) & (flat < upper_bound[i])
    flat[mask] = func(flat[mask], i)
```

That would avoid you of writing 100 lines if you have 100 ranges.

Comment: thanks that works.  as of now i would need 10 masks is there a better way than creating 10 masks?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is `flat[(flat >= 0.2) & (flat < 0.7)]` and similar. Note the right hand side of `flat[--] = func(--)`has to have the same number of elements, so you want call func on the indexed/masked array.

There are some NumPy functions that can help with this kind of code:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html